# Ikonli class is not found after jpackage

Tags: javafx, icons, fxml, classnotfoundexception, noclassdeffounderror

I am using Ikonli in my JavaFX application, with all the .jar files integrated into my project.

Everything works perfectly on Eclipse, and even after exporting to .jar, the application launches.

I create the .exe file and the application installs correctly but does not launch.

I then decide to recreate the .exe with the "--win-console" command from Jpackage to see what is wrong and I get this error message :

```
    javafx.fxml.LoadException:
    fr/raviel/player/view/RootLayout.fxml:33

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2685)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
    at fr.raviel.player.Player.initRootLayout(Player.java:40)
    at fr.raviel.player.Player.start(Player.java:28)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:447)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:262)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:54)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.applyProperty(FXMLLoader.java:522)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processValue(FXMLLoader.java:372)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processPropertyAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:334)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processInstancePropertyAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:244)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:777)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2924)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2639)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.ModuleHelper.invoke(ModuleHelper.java:98)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:258)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Logger
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.<clinit>(AbstractIkonResolver.java:32)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconLiteral(FontIcon.java:235)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 36 more
```

something is wrong here :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/logging/Logger
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.<clinit>(AbstractIkonResolver.java:32)
    at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconLiteral(FontIcon.java:235)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.logging.Logger
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:433)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:586)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 36 more
```

MANIFEST :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ javafx.base.jar javafx.controls.jar javafx.fxml.jar 
javafx.graphics.jar javafx.media.jar javafx.swing.jar javafx.web.jar ja
vafx-swt.jar org.eclipse.fx.ide.css.jfx8_3.7.0.202010120832.jar ikonli-
core-12.2.0.jar ikonli-javafx-12.2.0.jar ikonli-fontawesome-pack-12.2.0
.jar ikonli-material-pack-12.2.0.jar
Rsrc-Main-Class: fr.raviel.player.Player
Class-Path: .
```

Its been a week now that I have been looking, but I have not found any solution. Can someone help me. Thank you and sorry for my English.

Comment: Did you include the `java.logging` module in the custom run-time image built by `jpackage`?

Comment: The title is misleading. It is not the Ikonli class which is not found.

Comment: @Slaw No i just add javafx.controls, media, fxml, graphics jmods. I will try that

Comment: @Slaw Work very well, thank you so much